# Command Line Options For YUI Compressor

Tags: javascript, windows, yui, yui-compressor

This is probably a quick question.  I'd like to run the YUI compressor so that, instead of overwriting all of the javascript files in the input directory, it dumps the output files into a subdirectory called min.  I would like to do something like

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar -o *.js .\min\*.js c:\MyJavascriptDirectory\*.*
```

but instead it just overwrites the existing files with the minified files.  Does anyone know the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of the correct syntax to do that, but someone has made a modification so that you can set up your output directory as follows

```
java -jar yuicompressor.jar --output-dir /some/folder/for/compressed/js *js
```

This allows you to have a source folder and a compressed folder. As opposed to having source and a bunch of -min.js files in the same folder.

You can download the mod at the bottom of the page here http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/ticket/2528131

Answer (score 2):

`java -jar yuicompressor.jar -o '.js$:-min.js' *.js`  will minify all .js files and save them as -min.js then you could just move all those files: `mkdir min; mv *-min.js min/`.

[Source](https://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)

Comment: When I run this it results in an empty file named '.js$

Comment: @user2345998 this should still work. An (admittedly silly) example: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/491748561dce3c01f898).